# Develop ms access database app share with team

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, share

I want to develop form based application in ms access without share point any other method to share with my team. every team member can be access using through remotely.

If any body share another alternative idea it's pleasure for me.

Comment: What do you mean by 'remotely'? Not on LAN? Via internet? VPN? Maybe Office360?

Comment: i want to cloud based,

Comment: Isn't that what Office360 is all about?